# How to use Service Fabric Powershell cmdlets in an Azure Automation runbook

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I want to use an azure automation account to connect to a service fabric cluster and run a health check. I'm struggling with establishing a connection to the cluster because the service fabric sdk is not present.

Is there a way to use the service fabric powershell cmdlets in an azure automation runbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could import `AzureRM.ServiceFabric 0.2.4` module to Azure automation account. Open the link https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM.ServiceFabric/0.2.4 and click `Deploy to Azure Automation`.  Then, you could use some Service Fabric PowerShell cmdlets.

Another solution is using [Hybrid Runbook Worker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker).

> The Hybrid Runbook Worker feature of Azure Automation allows you to
>   run runbooks directly on the computer hosting the role and against
>   resources in the environment to manage those local resources.

You could install fabric cluster SDK on your local, and use Runbook worker to execute it.

Comment: Doesn't look like that module includes Connect-ServiceFabricCluster.

Comment: @AspiringTFSGuru Unfortunately, there is not `Connect-ServiceFabricCluster` cmdlet in the module. I search many times, I don't find the cmdlet that supported in the automation account.

Comment: So is there a way to install these cmdlets for use by the automation runbook?

Comment: @AspiringTFSGuru Currently, it is not possible.   Service Fabric SDK is not install on Azure Automation workers.

Comment: @AspiringTFSGuru Another solution is that you could use  [Hybrid Runbook Worker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker).  You could execute runbooks on a Hybrid Runbook Worker

Comment: The hybrid runbook worker approach worked! I spun up a VM in azure, installed the Service Fabric SDK, followed the docs and it all worked quite well. I ran into an access issue, but resolved that by adding a custom credential ([RunAs account](https://github.com/rgl/azure-content/blob/master/articles/automation/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker.md))