# Failure to connect to service fabric cluster from an Azure automation script

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-automation

I'm trying to connect to a Azure Service Fabric cluster from an Azure Automation PowerShell Runbook. I know there's a Hybrid Runbook-approach that possibly can resolve this (c.f. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45883580/how-to-use-service-fabric-powershell-cmdlets-in-an-azure-automation-runbook)) but for reasons specific to the project I'm working on I would prefer not to use it.
Instead I have used the method described [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/43c62759-82ef-4d7c-bdfb-71c23b9d1b6f/how-to-use-azure-automation-to-start-and-stop-the-service-fabric-nodes?forum=azureautomation) to import the SF modules into my automation account. This makes the `Connect-ServiceFabricCluster` cmdlet available to me but when executed it fails to connect. I have set up a non-secure test cluster and this is the runbook code:

```
Import-Module "ServiceFabric" # not sure this is needed...
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"

# Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
$servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

"Logging in to Azure..."
Add-AzureRmAccount `
    -ServicePrincipal `
    -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
    -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
    -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 


"Test connecting to cluster..."
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint 
'[myclusterendpointurl]:19000'
"Done!"
```

When run in the Test-pane (or run as a regular job, doesn't matter), three attempts to execute the script is done with this logged to the output each round:

```
Logging in to Azure...

Environments                                                                                                            

------------                                                                                                            

{[AzureChinaCloud, AzureChinaCloud], [AzureCloud, AzureCloud], 
[AzureGermanCloud, AzureGermanCloud], [AzureUSGovernme...

Test connecting to cluster...
```

until it finishes with an error:

```
The runbook job was attempted 3 times, but it failed each time.  Common 
reasons that runbook jobs fail can be found here:  
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-troubleshooting-automation-errors
```

The Connect-method just seems to time out without logging anything to the output. What goes on here?

Comment: In your modules, could you find cmdlet `Connect-ServiceFabricCluster`?

Comment: Yes, I can see it when I open up the module in the modules list.

Comment: Did you get any further with this? I'm getting the same issue, I have imported the module and can run the cmdlet to connect but it retries 3 times with zero output as to what is going on

Comment: No, I gave up on this. However, we are using an Azure automation runbook for bringing the cluster up/down according to a time schedule. These scripts operate on resources so no cluster connection is needed. For the installing/updating of applications & services (that's what we intended to use the connection for) we are currently using VSTS release defintions instead. In VSTS you can register ServiceFabric-cluster endpoints that you can use from within your release tasks. Releases can be set to run on schedules too.

Comment: Thanks, I also gave up on the runbook idea of connecting to the cluster, we wanted to use it to monitor the health of applications and remove unhealthy apps as we have found issues with unhealthy apps bringing the cluster down. Going with a C# approach now.